# UIActivityIndicator with UIWebView loadRequest?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl, uiactivityindicatorview

So I have a view containing a web view with HTML content. This is my code to display it :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWeb];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[vue loadRequest:request];
vue.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

This works well. But of course there is a little latency before the HTML content is displayed, and I want to display a UIActivityIndicator at this moment.

I know that I must use :

```
[myActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[myActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

The only thing I miss is how to know when the HTML content is completely loaded ?

Thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a Protocol that you can implement to know that, [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). If you implement the method [webViewDidFinishLoad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) you can know when the content are completely loaded:

Here is your code:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWeb];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[vue loadRequest:request];
vue.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

And here is the protocol methods

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Remember to set your class as a delegate of the UIWebView before load the request.

Answer (score 3):

In `UIWebViewDelegate` method,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [myActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    //myActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the didFinishLoading method of the UIWebView delegate.
More info here: [UIWebView finished loading Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662565/uiwebview-finished-loading-event) and, of course, on apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html